# Como repetir um bloco do Jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

Estou usando o [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) como mecanismo de template para gerar um site HTML estático num script Python.

Quero repetir o conteúdo de um bloco (*title*) no template de layout (*layout.html*), que está assim:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - {{ sitename }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</h1>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Esse template será estendido por outro parecido com esse:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}Titulo da pagina{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
Aqui vai o conteudo da pagina
{% endblock %}
```

Porém isso não funciona, resultando num erro:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: block 'title' defined twice
```

O jinja2 interpreta o segundo `{% block title %}` no *layout.html* como uma redefinição do bloco.

Como posso fazer para repetir o conteúdo de um bloco no mesmo template, com o jinja2?

Comment: Acabei de postar a mesma pergunta no SO pai: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929241/how-to-repeat-a-block-in-a-jinja2-template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [solução foi postada em resposta a minha pergunta no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929334/149872).

Basta usar a [variável especial `self`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#child-template) para accessar o o bloco por nome:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - {{ sitename }}</title>
<!-- ... snip ... -->
<h1>{{ self.title() }}</h1>
```